# Disable PositionItem in BindingNavigator

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I disabled the PositionItem box by using

```
BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Enabled = False
```

But each time I click to next row, it's being enabled again.

I even tried to force it to be disabled by adding

```
 Private Sub BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Click
    BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Enabled = False
 End Sub
```

How can I make control if it's enabled or not?

Comment: Try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/b7701c49-801e-4940-bfeb-a2e6d17d2b05)

Comment: well. it is good that i works for you.. i will put this in answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref: [MSDN - disable binding navigator](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/b7701c49-801e-4940-bfeb-a2e6d17d2b05)

BindingNavigator button's Click events has been default encapsulated behaviour to set other buttons' Enable property based on BindingNavigatorPosition, So you can either set the `Me.BindingNavigator1.PositionItem.Available = False` or `BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Visible = False`.

You can override the functionality of the events as:

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click  
  BindingNavigator1.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf DisableItems))  
End Sub 

Private Sub DisableItems()  
  BindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem.Enabled = False 
  BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Enabled = False 
  BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Enabled = False 
  BindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.Enabled = False 
  BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Enabled = False 
  BindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem.Enabled = False 
  BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Enabled = False 
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Enabled = False` statement at the **CotFocus Event Handler** of the **BindingNavigatorPositionItem**  as the following:

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorPositionItem_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object,
                                                  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorPositionItem.GotFocus
    BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Enabled = False
End Sub
```